# What are the equivalent to Matlab's ddencmp and wdencmp functions in python

Tags: python, matlab, wavelet

I developed some code in MATLAB and now I'm translating it to python but in MATLAB, I use the functions [`ddencmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/ddencmp.html) and [`wdencmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wdencmp.html) and I cannot find the equivalents in Python.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what library I can use for this purpose in Python?

Comment: You may find something of interest in [scipy.signal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html). I don't see anything equivalent to those MATLAB functions, but I'm not well-versed in signal processing, so perhaps I've missed them.

Comment: Maybe pywavelet (http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/#) will have similar functionality

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this person's code will help: [Denoising a signal with Pywavelet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636117/denoising-a-signal-with-pywavelet)

Just like @jme said try

> ```
> from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
> ```

I would comment, but I can't yet :P